# Compare Outlook time to time in Access recordset

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I loop through an Outlook folder to bring back records with received time greater than the most recent data in the table.

The code is working for every record apart from one.

The `If` evaluates this as true:

```vb
olItms.Item(i).ReceivedTime > dDateTime
```

where both values are: `19/06/2019 14:21:55`.

```vb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT EmailTime FROM tbl_EngagementData WHERE ReportID = """ & "Open Absence" & """" & " ORDER BY EmailTime DESC")
dDateTime = rs.Fields(0)
For i = olItms.Count To 1 Step -1
    If olItms.Item(i).ReceivedTime > dDateTime Then
        ' Do Something
    End If
Next
```

I expect that record to evaluate as False.

Comment: I think the issue is around the seconds-milliseconds, etc. part. Access and Outlook might have different precision. Convert the right and left hand sides to double, and see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
If DateDiff("s", dDateTime, olItms.Item(i).ReceivedTime) > 0 Then
```

Comment: Thank you, works great. I was suspecting that it might be seconds-milliseconds issues.